# Riverpod best practice - relevant variables into one big class?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/15gfrzm/riverpod_question_best_practices/?share_id=hnZ0zGwo41iRtaQED-4tE&utm_content=2&utm_medium=android_app&utm_name=androidcss&utm_source=share&utm_term=1

[image]

I'm bringing up this question that someone wrote 3 months ago because it mirrors the dilemma I'm facing now.

[image]
When looking at the "From ChangeNotifier" chapter in the Riverpod official documentation(https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_change_notifier), it seems like they prefer the second approach in the reddit link.

In my current project, I often have larger model classes with multiple variables. Should I be breaking all of these down and making each one its own provider? Is Riverpod's approach somewhat distant from the typical object-oriented design where data encapsulation is fundamental?

I'm curious about the opinions of many people.

Answer (score 1):

A notifier holds one object as `State`.  Because the provider holding the notifier has a lifecycle, it's important that the elements of the state have a related birth, update, and death cycle.  So I advise putting only related lifecycle items into a given notifier.